# How can I declare a variable of type List<string>?

Tags: typescript

I am using TypeScript and have a C# class with a property of type `List<string>`. I need to have the same type of property in TypeScript.

How can I declare a property in TypeScript class of type `List<string>`?

Comment: If you have a `List<>` class already defined, you already appear to know how to declare it. So, what's your question? Typescript doesn't add .NET classes.

Comment: His is asking how to create a member of a class that is of type List in TypeScript.

Comment: Use: var_name: Array<string>; or var_name: string[];

Answer (score 33):

`List<string>` is something specific to C# and depends upon the Base class library (BCL) support in .NET.

For TypeScript by default (without an external library like https://github.com/basarat/typescript-collections) you are limited to the built in JavaScript Array type. Here is a small sample to show its usage:

```
var foo:string[] = ['a','b']; 
foo.push('c');
console.log(foo) // [a,b,c]
```

Comment: This is how you declare a variable as a list.  You don't show how to create a *class member* of type list.

Comment: Class member ain't that different `class Foo { foo : string[] = ['a'] } ` @ftravers .See http://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/classes.html